# Dynamc slicers and pivot charts in excel using Java

Tags: java, apache

Do anyone have idea how to implement Dynamc slicers and pivot charts using any api.
I would appreciate if you could send me any link or clue how to do it.I need to implement this in our BI application.

Thanks for your help in advance!cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You may try jXLS, it may help with charts
http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/chartsample.html

I did not use it but with Apache POI as far as I know you cannot make dynamic charts.